# Maven excluding commons-logging

Tags: java, maven

I use maven, but when i build my project have a NoClassFound beacause commons-logging is not build in the final jar.

```
[INFO] Excluding commons-logging:commons-logging:jar:1.1.1 from the shaded 
jar.
[INFO] Including redis.clients:jedis:jar:2.9.0 in the shaded jar.
[INFO] Including org.apache.commons:commons-pool2:jar:2.4.2 in the shaded 
jar.
[INFO] Including org.apache.commons:commons-dbcp2:jar:2.1.1 in the shaded 
jar.
[INFO] Including mysql:mysql-connector-java:jar:5.1.38 in the shaded jar.
[INFO] Replacing original artifact with shaded artifact.
```

My pom:

```
<plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.1</version>
        <configuration>
            <artifactSet>
                <includes>
                    <include>redis.clients</include>
                    <include>org.apache.commons</include>
                    <include>org.apache.commons.logging</include>
                    <include>mysql</include>
                </includes>
            </artifactSet>
        </configuration>
        <executions>
            <execution>
                <phase>package</phase>
                <goals>
                    <goal>shade</goal>
                </goals>
            </execution>
        </executions>
    </plugin>
```

Y have multiple dependency, have : jedis, commons-dbcp2 (contains the logging), mysql-connector-java

Comment: Are you using eclipse?

Comment: No i use Intellij

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You included the groupIds

```
<include>redis.clients</include>
<include>org.apache.commons</include>
<include>org.apache.commons.logging</include>
<include>mysql</include>
```

so the jar does not include the groupId `commons-logging`.